# Automatically redirect to login page when session timeout

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, session-timeout

I wish to apply the same code in the header of all my jsf pages where it will automatically detect when the session is timeout and redirect to login page.

I have tried code from some online tutorial but fail to do this.

Can anyone teach me?

Comment: What did you try and where is it failing ?

Comment: 'Some online tutorial' is to vague.

Comment: PrimeFaces has an idle monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very good approach. Use simple login or session expiration filter:

[Example](http://www.itcuties.com/j2ee/jsf-2-login-filter-example/)

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

/**
 * Checks if user is logged in. If not it redirects to the login.xhtml page.
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Get the loginBean from session attribute
    LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean)((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getAttribute("loginBean");

    // For the first application request there is no loginBean in the session so user needs to log in
    // For other requests loginBean is present but we need to check if user has logged in successfully
    if (loginBean == null || !loginBean.isLoggedIn()) {
        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/login.xhtml");
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // Nothing to do here!
}

public void destroy() {
    // Nothing to do here!
}
```

}

web.xml

```
    <!-- Login filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.examples.webapps.filterlogin.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I think you mean to use `/*` in `<url-pattern>` but with that config, this filter will intercept even requests for static resources like js and css files and redirect them to login page initially when your requested for login page :)

Comment: Yes, sure!:) It is just example. To exclude static content we may use something like this: `<filter>
    <filter-name>theFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.demo.CustomServletFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
 <param-name>excludePatterns</param-name>
 <param-value>public/*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>` and in filter get them `this.excludePatterns = cfg.getInitParameter("excludePatterns");` parse and check.

Comment: Can I know why did you write -> It is not very good approach?

Comment: It is only my point of view. JSF page it is "view" (in context of MVC pattern). Add logic on "view" which will check session not very good solution. Filters was designed specifically for such things.

Comment: Just adding few missing pieces.. You should configure session-timeout in your web.xml. Also this filter is checking for login object in session only when there's an actual request from the browser but you should also have a client side javascript timer to send the request on expiry

Comment: There is no need to add any javascript. We have to check session expiration in filter only. For example we will have two filters: one for login and one for session.

Comment: I face this problem after applying your code. -> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed in the line of  chain.doFilter(request, response);

Comment: And I have another problem. it can redirect to login page, but not automatically. I still need to click a button or link to trigger the filter. Any idea on this?

Comment: Yes, you will be redirected only during the request to server. But what do you mean by "redirect automatically"? About the error. Looks like you want to sendError() after chain.doFilter(request, response).

Answer (score 1):

Being on the server side, your code can be made aware of session time out. Using that, you can set a cookie which indicates when the actual session timeout happens (its not mentioned whether active session timeout or idle timeout). A javascript running on the page can read the cookie in a timed manner and redirect the user if timeout value is crossed.

This is one of many approaches, hope it helps.

I believe Filter is not a required approach here as the requirement refers to **automatic redirection to login screen**.

Comment: This one looks good to me. But I think, people are often implementing idle timeout which has to start the timer only when the user is not interacting with the application and reset the timer on any user action. Also you can get the timeout value from server in html as a global javascript variable not necessarily in a cookie :)

Comment: Exactly, cookie was just a way I mentioned, though not really recommended. We had one application where we even tracked mouse moves / key strokes to compute idle timeout instead of usual server interaction.


One more point of note, if the application is expecting more of user typing before submission, its better to keep interacting with server through background ajax calls just to ensure server does not go through "idle timeout" due to lack of server interaction, though our JS code on client knows user is actively typing.

Comment: Like I said, any user interaction not just with the server ;) and it's a pain to track all those events, but Fortunately so many people wrote js plugins to make our lives easy

Comment: Good point :) reminding the server that the user is still using the application is important but with our highly responsive apps, we're more likely to talk to server for any view updates